# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel while calling java web service using SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: web-services, ssl, soap, httpwebrequest, channel

I have got an exception:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

While calling java web service using `SoapHttpClientProtocol` the service enables `TLS 1.2`.

**Client:** Windows 10 
**Host service:** Windows Server 2016 
**Application (client/server):** Frameworke 4.6.2

I have added below code  before create `HttpWebRequest` and still get same exception:

> System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
> System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
> ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (snder, cert, chain, error) => true;